# Youtube API - Querying JSON for a video id loads empty embedded iframe 

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, youtube-api, json-c

I put it all here: http://jsfiddle.net/uJ3h7/

But I'll repost the mark-up here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/MisterAngelMarino/favorites?v=2&alt=jsonc&max-results=1",function(json){
$.each(json.data, function(i,video){
var source = video.id
$("#video").append('<iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ source + '?html5=1&theme=dark&showinfo=0&modestbranding=1&controls=0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');    
    });
});
});



<div id="video"></div>
```

Any ideas what I borked?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

http://jsfiddle.net/pKZPP/

Comment: Wow, thanks! :D I think I can see what I did wrong, but would you mind elaborating? Basically when you parse JSON results you have to include the entire string?

Comment: You could use a variable to shorten things: http://jsfiddle.net/BqMmU/ or in your case (max-results=1) you dont even need a loop: http://jsfiddle.net/P22vh/